# What does "pull over on to the hard shoulder" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

As per Oxford dictionary, the definition of [*pull over*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pull_over) is the following:

> PHRASAL VERB
>    (of a vehicle) move to the side of or off the road.
>
> > Joy decided to pull over on to the hard shoulder.

I am not clear about the meaning of above sentence. Does it mean that Joy was lying on a bed in the supine posture, then he decided to turn to the side of the hard shoulder, in order to take side sleep posture? Otherwise, how can one move to the side of the hard shoulder?

I want to understand whether this sentence has quite a different meaning from what I understood.

Comment: Please give the reason for negative rating

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you seem to have missed the actual definition altogether. It doesn't mention beds, but vehicles.

Comment: If you look up `"shoulder of the road"` on Google images, you'll find lots of pictures like [this one](http://www.clrp.cornell.edu/images/newsletter/articles/2013/bike1.jpg). (The cyclist is riding on the hard shoulder in that picture.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'hard shoulder' refers to the lane at the side of a road where a car can pull into if it breaks down or needs to stop in an emergency.

Comment: +1. And if the area beside the road is unpaved it can be called a "soft shoulder" (at least in the US). https://www.google.com/search?q=warning+soft+shoulder&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig1JGlmZ3WAhUL2oMKHY-bBiQQ_AUICigB&biw=1743&bih=794#imgrc=DyYJxGkg4a2PbM: